# Oracle SQL regexp_like by unicode types

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, regexp-like

Let's say I have a pattern in unicode types (or Unicode Categories, according to https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

```
LLLLZLLLZLLLL
NNNN
```

I'm trying to write a sql query, selecting entries in the column which corresponds exactly to the pattern.

I do have entry "2343" in this column, along with many other mixed Letter-Number, or longer (more than 4) Number unicode characters.

I want to retrieve exactly "2343", (or any 4 unicode numbers entry).

Tried a few, for example

```
SELECT field1 
FROM myTable1 
WHERE regexp_like(field1, '[^\p{N}{4}S]');

SELECT field1 
FROM myTable1 
WHERE regexp_like(field1, '[^\p{N}\p{N}\p{N}\p{N}S]');
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Please tag with your oracle version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that's not the oracle syntax for unicode character classes.

Try `[:digit:]` for any digit.

see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)

Answer (score 0):

thank you @1010! You pushed me into right direction!
These work for me:

```
4987  -  NNNN
```

```
SELECT field1 
FROM myTable1 
WHERE regexp_like(field1, '^[[:digit:]]{4}$');
```

```
Ivan Joe Test - LLLLZLLLZLLLL
```

```
SELECT field1 
FROM myTable1 
WHERE regexp_like(field1, '^[[:alpha:]]{4}[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]{3}[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]{4}$');
```